# How do I populate a bash associative array with command output?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to populate an associative array with the output of a command. I can do it without a command as:

```
$ declare -A x=( [first]=foo [second]=bar )
$ echo "${x[first]}, ${x[second]}"
foo, bar
```

and I can populate a non-associative array with command output as:

```
$ declare y=( $(echo 'foo bar') )
$ echo "${y[0]}, ${y[1]}"
foo, bar
```

but when I try to build on both of the above to create a statement that will populate an associative array from a command, I get the following error message:

```
$ declare -A z=( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )
-bash: z: $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'): must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

Why am I getting that error message and what is the correct syntax to populate an associative array with the output of a command? I am trying to avoid using `eval` for [the usual reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=shell+eval+evil&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), do not want to use a temp file, and of course `echo` is just being used as an example of a command that produces the effect in question, the real command will be more complicated.

So, based on a couple of the answers below, it looks like it was just my quoting that was a problem:

```
$ declare -A z="( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )"
$ echo "${z[first]}, ${z[second]}"
foo, bar
```

and with spaces in the indices and values:

```
$ declare -A z="( $(echo '[first field]="foo with space" [second]="space bar"') )"
$ echo "${z[first field]}, ${z[second]}"
foo with space, space bar
```

---

EDIT in response to a question in the comments about why the quotes are necessary ([How do I populate a bash associative array with command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417793/how-do-i-populate-a-bash-associative-array-with-command-output#comment105347762_39418782)) - I don't exactly know but maybe someone else can explain using the results of this script as reference (not expecting the specified indices to be used in the indexed arrays, they're just part of the strings being populated as the array values):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

set -x

printf 'Indexed, no quotes\n'
declare -a w=( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )
declare -p w

printf '\n---\n'

printf 'Indexed, with quotes\n'
declare -a x="( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )"
declare -p x

printf '\n---\n'

printf 'Associative, no quotes\n'
declare -A y="( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )"
declare -p y

printf '\n---\n'

printf 'Associative, with quotes\n'
declare -A z=( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )
declare -p z
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh
+ printf 'Indexed, no quotes\n'
Indexed, no quotes
+ w=($(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'))
++ echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'
+ declare -a w
+ declare -p w
declare -a w=([0]="[first]=foo" [1]="[second]=bar")
+ printf '\n---\n'

---
+ printf 'Indexed, with quotes\n'
Indexed, with quotes
++ echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'
+ declare -a 'x=( [first]=foo [second]=bar )'
+ declare -p x
declare -a x=([0]="bar")
+ printf '\n---\n'

---
+ printf 'Associative, no quotes\n'
Associative, no quotes
++ echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'
+ declare -A 'y=( [first]=foo [second]=bar )'
+ declare -p y
declare -A y=([second]="bar" [first]="foo" )
+ printf '\n---\n'

---
+ printf 'Associative, with quotes\n'
Associative, with quotes
+ z=($(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'))
./tst.sh: line 24: z: $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'): must use subscript when assigning associative array
+ declare -A z
+ declare -p z
declare -A z=()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a traditional while loop approach to populate an associative array from a command's output:

```
while IFS= read -r; do
   declare -A z+="( $REPLY )"
done < <(printf '[first]=foo [second]=bar\n[third]=baz\n')

# check output
$> echo "${z[first]}, ${z[second]}, ${z[third]}"
foo, bar, baz

# or declare -p
$> declare -p z
declare -A z='([third]="baz" [second]="bar" [first]="foo" )'
```

**EDIT:** Your original attempt will also work with proper quotes:

```
$> unset z

$> declare -A z="( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )"

$> declare -p z
declare -A z='([second]="bar" [first]="foo" )'
```

Comment: That could work. We'd need to add a `IFS=` to it and we can't use `$'...'` around the whole thing or it'd convert `\t` to a tab, etc. but we could probably get literal newlines or even NUL characters (and read with NUL flag) between each array element. Gotta think about that too, thanks!

Comment: I was once told on SO that `IFS=` is not needed if we are using internal  `$REPLY` variable but there is no harm in using it I guess. (edited)

Comment: Hmm, the newlines aren't actually making a difference in separating the values,. the script works when the values are just space-separated, the printf just needs one newline at the end.

Comment: Yeah but my point is you don't need it or even the loop, this works just the same: `declare -A z+="( $(printf '[first]=foo [second]=bar [third]=baz\n') )"` and produces the desired output: `echo "${z[first]}, ${z[second]}, ${z[third]}"` outputs `foo, bar, baz`. So what's different about this vs my original attempt? Hmmm....

Comment: Ah now I got it. You just needed quote so `declare -A z="( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )"` would work fine but `declare -A z=( $(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar') )` will give error.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted that at the end of [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39417793/1745001). Can't believe I got bit by not quoting something! Now need to expand it to get the syntax right for handling blank chars in the index and/or value. I'll accept this answer later today unless someone comes along with a good reason not and and a better alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Do we know why the quoting is needed?

Comment: @kvantour I can't give you C&V so I added a script and it's output to the bottom of my question to see if anyone else wants to chime in. It might be worth asking a new question about if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine this is somewhat brittle, but you can make the entire `z=(...)` assignment the result of a command substitution.

```
declare -A "$(echo z="($(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'))")"
```

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought of that. Probably don't want to use `echo z=...` but some variation of `printf 'z="%s" ....'` might be robust. Gotta think about that! Thanks.

Comment: The correct ending should be `)")"` not `"))"`, but that's not enough for an edit :)

Comment: I guess since there is no unquoted `(` for the unquoted `)` to pair up with, it doesn't need to be quoted. Fixed anyway, because I'm sure that some other input could probably tip it from working to not-working.

Comment: Looks like all I needed was to quote my original assignment, see the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/a/39418782/1745001. A tad embarrassing... Thanks again.

Comment: Huh. Did I really not try that before the nested monstrosity suggested here?

Answer (score 1):

Given that this works:

```
declare -A z=([first]=$(echo 'foo') [second]=$(echo 'bar'))
```

I'm guessing that Bash needs to see the associative array initialization list before doing any substitutions. So I don't see a way to avoid `eval`:

```
eval "declare -A z=($(echo '[first]=foo [second]=bar'))"
```

What is a "usual reason" to avoid `eval`?

Comment: Google [shell eval evil](https://www.google.com/search?q=shell+eval+evil&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for many discussions on the issues around `eval`. Thanks for the response, still hoping there's an alternative.

Comment: Looks like all I needed was to quote my original assignment, see the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/a/39418782/1745001. A tad embarrassing... Thanks again.