# Best/optimized way to search/lookup text in a file in BASH scripts

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I have a file with hundreds of thousands records. All these records are unique, comma separated values. First column can be considered the key, and second column is the value of interest.

The file size would be 8 to 10 MBs. I have to lookup these value time to time in a script. Currently I am using below grep statement:

> myvalue=$(grep $myvar filename | cut -d, -f2)

It works fine, but the real problem is multiple/sequential lookups to same file. I think it is not very optimized way as I have to lookup from same file multiple times (more than 100-200 times ) during my script run so each time it'll grep the entire file. I want some better/optimized way.

**update**
Important to note that it is sequential script, and all the values in $myvar are generated during runtime, so I can't have all the values available and do a combined lookup, it has to be one value lookup in each iteration

Comment: It's not at all optimized. Use a programming language that lets you index the data first, then use the index for your queries.

Comment: It's a shell script that I use to login multiple devices, so can't change that,

Comment: Why not? What does performing several hundred queries of multi-megabyte files have to do with logging into another machine?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is a shell script and the values are generated in real time, so I have to lookup these values during the script run,

Comment: If the values you are looking up are generated at real time, that does not affect your ability to index the original data before hand.

Comment: Please suggest how? Or what language I can use in that shell script?

Comment: Have a look at `mapfile` here https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/mapfile.htm

Comment: When you write: _I have to lookup these value time to time in a script._ Do you mean that _you have the run the scipt multiple times and each time you run it, it needs to do such a lookup_, or do you mean _you run the script ones, but you have to perfom that lookup multiple times during a single run_

Comment: the later; script runs once and and I have to perform multiple lookups during the single run,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is constructed once and then referenced over and over without being changed in between, you need to use an associative array as a lookup table. That might get big and ugly in bash; consider perl instead.

However, you asked how to do it in bash.

```
$: eval "declare -A lookup=(
   $( sed -E 's/^([^,]+),([^,]+).*/  [\1]=\2/' filename )
   )"
```

Now all the values should be in the table `lookup`.

An *associative* array uses strings as its keys instead of integers, so this sets the keys and values as pairs in a table.

```
sed -E 's/^([^,]+),([^,]+).*/  [\1]=\2/'
```

takes the first and second fields of the comma-delimited file and reformats them into key/value assignments in bash syntax, like this:

```
declare -A lookup=(
   [a]=1
   [b]=2
   [c]=3 # ... and so on
)
```

The `eval` parses all that into the current environment for your use.

No more `grep`'s. Just use `"${lookup[$myvar]}"`.
If you just wanted to assign it for readability, then instead of the `grep` use

```
myvalue="${lookup[$myvar]}"
```

My local example in use:

```
$: cat x
a,1,lijhgf
b,2,;lsaoidj
c,3,;l'skd

$: echo "declare -A lookup=(
   $( sed -E 's/^([^,]+),([^,]+).*/  [\1]=\2/' x )
   )"
   declare -A lookup=(
     [a]=1
     [b]=2
     [c]=3
   )

$: eval "declare -A lookup=(
   $( sed -E 's/^([^,]+),([^,]+),.*/  [\1]=\2/' x )
   )"

$: echo "${lookup[b]}"
   2
```

Comment: Yeah, that's correct,  the file doesn't change. Your solution sounds interesting, I'll check and do some benchmarking and let you know

Comment: I am seeing this error when trying to load the file in array `must use subscript when assigning associative array`

Comment: Replace the `eval` with just `echo` and throw it to a file so you can check the syntax looks like the example I gave. `declare -A lookup=( [a]=1 [b]=2 [c]=3 )` - you should be able to say something like `echo ${lookup[b]}` and see the right value if you source the file.

Comment: I did echo and values are not coming as your example, rather simply comma separated keys and values only... Something wrong with sed statement I think

Comment: aah, I think in my case the difference is the input file. it has only two columns, when I use contents of your file x, it works fine, but when I removed the third column, it prints same thing: keys,values as it was printing for my original file. So need to adjust the sed statement.

Comment: replaced the `,.*` with `.*`from the end of sed expression, and it is working fine now as I don't have second comma in my file :) thanks a lot for your support

Comment: Got it. Sorry, was being overly cautious. I had actually done that as well at one point, and one of the three `sed`'s here was like that, lol... I updated it here so they match. :) You're quite welcome. How's the benchmark? Saving lots of time?

Comment: yeah, its amazing improvement, my initial setup was like plain `while read` and then grep each line, which took about 5 minutes and only looked up 30K values, while using arrays while I load the file, it took about 18 seconds to load and then printing all the records (almost 200K) took less then 2 seconds.

Comment: As you mentioned in your first comment, is it possible to use Perl hash in a shell script?

Comment: It's possible in a *perl* script, which will have much finer tools for complex programming with advanced maths and efficient streaming of data, and large, fast, complex memory structures. YMMV, but for big projects, you might be surprised what you can do in bash (and I have), but different languages specialize in diffrent things. Bash makes quick composition on the command line possible, focusing on a scriptable *interface*. It *can* do lots, but other languages do some of those things better. For example, bash has no multidimensional arrays at all.

Answer (score 2):

On of the obvious things I'm thinking of is the limitation of `grep` results, which can be done with the `-m` switch:

```
Prompt>cat test.txt
a
a
b
a
b

Prompt>grep "a" test.txt
a
a
a

Prompt>grep -m 1 "a" test.txt
a
```

Comment: -m will definitely improve the situation, but still each time the file has to be looked up, I am looking for some alternate, like maybe loading the entire file once in some sort of dictionary, or array maybe,

Answer (score 2):

First of all, lets look at your command:

```
myvalue=$(grep $myvar filename | cut -d, -f2)
```

You make use of 2 binaries which you load (`grep` and `cut`) to process the data. You should attempt to reduce this to a single binary. This will already help a lot:

```
myvalue=$(awk -F, -v var="$myvar" '$0~var { print $2; exit}' filename)
```

This will be much faster as:

- it is a single library
- stops reading the file from the moment the entry is found

If you need to do multiple lookups based on the key which is located in the first column, you can do the following in bash:

```
 while IFS= read -r; do
    declare -A z+="( $REPLY )"
 done < <(awk -F, '{print "["$1"]="$0}' lookupfile)

 echo ${z[$key]}
```

based on [How do I populate a bash associative array with command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417793/how-do-i-populate-a-bash-associative-array-with-command-output)